# How to query AWS services without specific region

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-regions

I am using AWS .Net SDK and trying to query AWS services by creating appropriate client like below

```
var cred = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKeyId);
using (AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(cred, region))
{
    // code here  
}
```

above works fine, but there is an overloaded method of AmazonEC2Client as well which does not require region to specify but when I try to create client without region like below then it gives error: `Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured`

> No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

```
using (AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(cred))
{
    // code here  
}
```

Please let me know if there is something wrong with above code or is there any way to query AWS services regardless of the region.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the region globally using the `AWSConfigs.AWSRegion` property.

```
AWSConfigs.AWSRegion = "us-east-1";
using (var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client())
{
  // Make request to Amazon EC2 using ec2Client
}
```

or you can set the `AWSRegion` key in the `appSettings` section of the `app.config` file.

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-west-2"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-region-selection.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in the code snippet you have shared, we still need to specify region somewhere.. isn't there a way to get the resources without region and return resources in all regions?

Comment: @VickyKhichar no, you have to specify a region. Each region has a separate AWS API endpoint. There is no way to get resources from all regions in a single API call.